# /usr/local/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:10: fatal error: limits.h: No such #12 39.40 file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, alpine-linux

when I tried to use `python:3.10-alpine3.18` as the docker base image like this:

```
FROM python:3.10-alpine3.18

MAINTAINER jiangxiaoqiang (jiangtingqiang@gmail.com)

ENV LANG=en_US.UTF-8 \
    LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 \
    TZ=Asia/Shanghai

RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone \
    && mkdir -p /root/visa \
    && apk update \
    && apk add gcc wget curl vim

RUN pip install pdm
ADD . /root/visa/
WORKDIR /root/visa/
RUN pdm install
ENTRYPOINT exec /root/visa/scripts/startup-app.sh
```

shows error like this:

```
2 39.40 generating cffi module 
#12 39.40 'build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/curl_cffi._wrapper.c'
#12 39.40 already up-to-date
#12 39.40 building 'curl_cffi._wrapper' extension
#12 39.40 gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC 
#12 39.40 -Icurl_cffi/include -Icurl_cffi/ffi -I/root/visa/.venv/include 
#12 39.40 -I/usr/local/include/python3.10 -c 
#12 39.40 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/curl_cffi._wrapper.c -o 
#12 39.40 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/curl_cff
#12 39.40 i._wrapper.o
#12 39.40 In file included from 
#12 39.40 build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-310/curl_cffi._wrapper.c:57:
#12 39.40 /usr/local/include/python3.10/Python.h:11:10: fatal error: limits.h: No such 
#12 39.40 file or directory
#12 39.40    11 | #include <limits.h>
#12 39.40       |          ^~~~~~~~~~
#12 39.40 compilation terminated.
#12 39.40 error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
#12 39.40 add pycurl failed:
#12 39.40 Traceback (most recent call last):
#12 39.40   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
#12 39.40     result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
#12 39.40   File
```

Am I missing something? is it possible to fixed this issue?

Comment: try to add `musl-dev` to your `apk add` call